# Issue on renaming functions

Tags: r, function, derivative

I'm writing some code to calculate derivatives of functions. I managed to generate 1st and 2nd derivatives for 1 variable and store in the environment as functions, so I can plot them later. Now I'm trying to calculate the partial derivates for equations with 2 or more variables and I can't find the code that can generate as much functions in the environment as partial derivatives of the function.

To clarify, for 1 variable I used:

```
    f <- function(x) cos(20*x)*exp(-1*x)
    F.<- function (x) eval(D(as.expression(body(f)), "x"))
    F..<- function (x) eval(D(as.expression(D(as.expression(body(f)), "x")),"x"))
```

and it worked perfect, I get the 3 functions in the environment:
[image: functions]

But for more than 1 variable I have to loop through this functions and generate as many funtions as partial derivatives of the equation.

My question is: how can I generate a loop that calculates the partial derivatives of a function and stores them as functions, each one with a custom name?

I tried the derivative function inside a for loop but couldn't manage to define different names for each calculation of the derivatives:

```
    for (i in 1:nro_variables) {
      var_D = vector_variables[i]  
      F.<- function (x) eval(D(as.expression(body(f)), var_D))
    }
```

Comment: Can you give an example of a function that has more than one variable and the output that you would expect to get for that input? That way possible solutions can be tested and verified.

Comment: @MrFlick, yes. Say I define function "f" as: f=  -log(1-x-y)-log(x)-log(y). its partial derivatives are:  F.= 1/(1-x-y)-1/x with respect to "x", and F.= 1/(1-x-y)-1/y with respect to "y".  I'm trying to get both equations stored in the environment with different name (eg: "F.x" for the partial derivative with respect to "x" and "F.y" for the partial with respect to "y")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to avoiding the use of assigning many separate similar objects to flood your global environment, consider using a single list that can index elements for better serial organization. See @GregorThomas's best practices [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/1422451) advocating:

> Don't ever create `d1` `d2` `d3`, ..., `dn` in the first place. Create a list `d` with `n` elements.

Specifically, if `vector_variables` is a character vector, `sapply` using `simplify=FALSE` will return a named list of functions. And yes, functions within lists can still be called.

```r
partial_deriv_funcs <- sapply(vector_variables, function(var_D) {
    f <- function(x) cos(20*x)*exp(-1*x)
    return(function(x) eval(D(as.expression(body(f)), var_D)))
}, simplify = FALSE)
```

To call function elements singularly or iteratively:

```r
# CALL SINGLE FUNCTION WITH SINGLE PARAM
result <- partial_deriv_funcs[['var1']](param)

# CALL SAME FUNCTION WITH VECTOR OF PARAMS
results <- lapply(param_vector, partial_deriv_funcs[['var1']])

# CALL ALL FUNCTIONS USING SAME PARAM
results <- lapply(partial_deriv_funcs, function(f) f(param))

# CALL ALL FUNCTIONS EACH WITH DIFFERENT PARAM
results <- mapply(function(f,p) f(p), partial_deriv_funcs, param_per_func_vector, SIMPLIFY= FALSE)
results <- Map(function(f,p) f(p), partial_deriv_funcs, param_per_func_vector) # EQUIVALENT
```

Comment: Thanks @Parfait, it worked great!. I added a For...loop to add the 'Environment' value of each element on the list and changed the default value (vector_variables) by the variable selected for the partial derivative. Now I can print the derivative equation and use it to evaluate values and plot them.

Comment: Excellent! Great to hear and glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

`eval` and `parse` can be used to define the function and `assign` can give it the correct name.

```
f <- function(x) 2 * x
g <- function(x, y) x * y
h <- function(x, y, z) x * y + z

fns <- c("f", "g", "h")

for (fn in fns) {
  for (variable in formalArgs(fn)) {
    function_name <- glue::glue("{toupper(fn)}.{variable}")
    fn_definition <- eval(parse(text = glue::glue("function({paste0(formalArgs(fn), collapse = ',')}) eval(D(as.expression(body({fn})), '{variable}'))")))

    assign(
      function_name,
      fn_definition
    )
  }
}

ls.str(mode = "function")
#> f : function (x)  
#> F.x : function (x)  
#> fn_definition : function (x, y, z)  
#> g : function (x, y)  
#> G.x : function (x, y)  
#> G.y : function (x, y)  
#> h : function (x, y, z)  
#> H.x : function (x, y, z)  
#> H.y : function (x, y, z)  
#> H.z : function (x, y, z)
```